Laravel 419 Error for Some Mobile Users Despite Correct CSRF Implementation
I'm encountering a persistent issue with my Laravel application where some users experience a 419 error. This happens inconsistently and primarily affects mobile users. Despite following various solutions, the problem persists for a subset of users.
Issue Details:

Error: Users receive a 419 error (Page Expired) on certain requests.
Occurrence: The error occurs for some users, not all. It seems random and primarily affects users on mobile browsers.
Testing: I have tested extensively on Chrome and Firefox on both my laptop and mobile, and I cannot reproduce the error myself.
Observed Behavior: Logs indicate that a new session is being created for each request for users experiencing this issue.

Solutions Tried:

CSRF Token: Ensured that the CSRF token is included in the form.
Session Configuration: Checked and confirmed the settings in config/session.php, including the SESSION_DOMAIN setting.
Session Expiry: Verified the session expiry settings.
User System Time: Ensured that the system time of users is correct.
Session Storage: Verified that session files are being created correctly on the server.
Mobile Browsers: The issue seems to occur only for users on mobile browsers, though I haven't been able to replicate it on my own mobile browser.
AJAX Usage: I do not use AJAX in my application.

Request:

Debugging Steps: How can I effectively debug this issue and pinpoint the cause?
Logger Usage: How should I utilize Laravel's logging system to capture relevant information? Where exactly should I place the logging code to capture the session creation and CSRF validation process?
Past Experiences: Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? What potential causes should I investigate further?

References:
I have already looked into the following Stack Overflow posts but they did not resolve my issue:

Post Request in Laravel Error 419
419 Page Expired in Laravel even after adding CSRF token

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
